# switch case with an if statement not working when true

Tags: if-statement, arduino, switch-statement

i am using a switch case with an if statement inside to help with touch screen touches

the following code is returning true Via serial terminal by confirming touch coordinates the value page is set in the beginning of the code to 0 until main screen loads then it switches to 1 (again confirmed by serial terminal) but even though i have confirmed all is true it will not run the true event (which is just a serial print command at the moment.

```
int page = 0;     // page number active
```

this is at the top of the code with the includes

then in the main loop

```
     switch (page) {

     // --------------check to see if screen 1 is loaded-----------------

  case '2': {  // Screen 1 Active As when screen 1 loads it chages the value of page to 1
    if ((p.x > 137 && p.x < 210)&& (p.y > 280 && p.y < 320)) 
   Serial.print("option1");       

   else if ((p.x > 80 && p.x < 112)&& (p.y > 280 && p.y < 320)) 
   Serial.print("option1.2");

      else if ((p.x > 45 && p.x < 85)&& (p.y > 280 && p.y < 320)) 
   Serial.print("option1.3");

      else if ((p.x > 5 && p.x < 24)&& (p.y > 280 && p.y < 320)) 
   Serial.print("option1.4");
 break;}
```

the main screen loads after setup and turns page to value 1

```
void mainmenu(){
  page = 1;
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
    Serial.println("failed!");
  }
  Serial.println("OK!");
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  Title();
  Grid();
  Buttons();
  {
```

values returned from serial terminal after pressing button 1

```
p.x is more than 137
p.x is less than 210
p.y is more than 280
p.x is less than 320
 X 196 & Y 310  Page Value= 1
```

but still no message Serial.print("option1")

i have broken down the if statement into its separate values and each returns true
so all i can think of it's something in the case line but i'm not to sure what

Comment: Page is an int and you are trying to match it against (int)'2', is it right to you?

Comment: can you please explain this is the first time i have used switch case sorry

Comment: You say that `page` assumes the vale `1` as an integer, so the correct line to match it is `case 1:`. You should match against integers, not chars converted to integers by an implicit cast.

Comment: As @skypjack pointed out (and  @Gianluca Colombo corrected in the answer) you were comparing page with the integer cast of '2'. Now, '2' is the way to express "the value of character '2' in the ascii table", which corresponds to 50. So your `case '2':` was equal to `case 50:`. If you want to compare to 2, you should write `case 2:`, without the quotes, as in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to change this line

```
case '2': {
```

with this one?

```
case 2: {
```

Also try to put a println after case to be sure that the switch statement works fine

```
case 2: { 
          Serial.println("Entered in case 2");
```

Comment: Brilliant you genius cracked it case 1:  i've been at this all day with a 2 page arduino forum post and no one got it